# Как сделать синхронную анимацию на Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру Match3 на unity (C#). Мне нужно синхронизировать анимацию отдельных элементов в Unity (C#), при выделение одно элемента анимация включается и если собрать три элемента в ряд, то анимация должна синхронно сработать на трёх элементах, подскажите как её синхронизировать. желательно кодом.

Comment: Если анимируете Вы сами через код, кадр за кадром, то запускайте анимацию у необходимых объектов одновременно через код в одной точке, например, в коде контроллера игрового поля.

Если же анимация через Animator - то запускаете нужную анимацию у необходимых объектов так же из одной точки одновременно, как описано выше. Или меняете параметр аниматоров (опять-таки одновременно) для того, что бы машина состояний включила нужную анимацию.

Answer (score 0):

Может запустить анимацию всех элементов, только тогда, когда isMatched(собрано 3)?  Или после того как собрал 3 или больше, запустить корутины на доли секунды, и после небольшой паузы запустить анимацию этих элементов